# matplotilib - instantiating an Axis from matplotlib.axis.py

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on a project where we have to implement a feature for matplotlib. We had to change the code in the Axis class. I have to write unit tests to make sure the things we added work as expected. I have to instantiate an Axis() object, but I don't know how to that. I've searched through the examples but they all use pyplot. Even the code in tests/test_axes.py uses pyplot. Is there a way to instantiate an Axis?

Answer (score 1):

Most pyplot commands instantiate an `Axes`. E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.gca()
print (ax, type(ax))
```

gives you an `Axes` as `ax`. The code prints

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B8AB0B8>, 
<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
```

Further examples, which all give you an Axes instance:

```
#1
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#2
ax = plt.gcf().add_subplot(111)
#3
ax = plt.gcf().add_axes([.1,.1,.9,.9])
```

You simply don't gain anything by not using pyplot.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to instantiate an [Axis](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis) object directly from matplotlib.axis.py without sub-classing it (like you did i guess) and overriding the methods that raise a `NotImplementedError`.

However, the derived classes `XAxis` and `YAxis` can be directly instantiated. This can be done without the pyplot interface using the matplotlib Object Oriented API like that :

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib.axis import XAxis, YAxis

fig = Figure()
ax = Axes(fig, [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

xaxis = XAxis(ax)
yaxis = YAxis(ax)

print(xaxis, type(xaxis))
print(yaxis, type(yaxis))
```

running the code results in :

```
XAxis(64.000000,48.000000) <class 'matplotlib.axis.XAxis'>
YAxis(64.000000,48.000000) <class 'matplotlib.axis.YAxis'>
```

I guess the same structure of code should also work to instantiate your own implementation of the Axis class.